# How do I stop Zombie Villagers from spawning or Zombies

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am making a flat adventure/Survival map which is meant to be played for maybe a year or two and is made to make the game harder.

In the map when you spawn you have a big shop which is setted up with custom villagers using a online generator. There are 2 types of villagers one that sells items and one that buys items. Keep in mind the currency is emeralds.

But the problem is that zombie villagers are able to spawn within the world and I have only intended that the only way to achieve emeralds is by trading with the villagers within the shop.

I want some way to make them despawn or teleporting them to the void.

Keep in mind im not able to remove normal zombies due to that an important item within the shop is zombie flesh.

Answer (score 3):

You will have to label zombies based on their `IsVillager` byte tag and then run commands based on the label.

#### 1.8

Objective to use.

```
/scoreboard objectives add ZombieVillager dummy
```

Commands to run in numerical order.

1. Set the "ZombieVillager" score to 1 for zombies with `IsVillager` set to 1.

   ```
   /scoreboard players set @e[type=Zombie] ZombieVillager 1 {IsVillager:1b}
   ```
2. Teleport those zombies to the void.

   ```
   /tp @e[type=Zombie,score_ZombieVillager_min=1] ~ -64 ~
   ```

#### 1.9

Commands to run in numerical order.

1. Apply "ZombieVillager" label for zombies with `IsVillager` set to 1.

   ```
   /scoreboard players tag @e[type=Zombie,tag=!ZombieVillager] add ZombieVillager {IsVillager:1b}
   ```
2. Teleport those zombies to the void.

   ```
   /tp @e[type=Zombie,tag=ZombieVillager] ~ -64 ~
   ```

Comment: Sorry to have watsed your time but I managed to fix the problem by only removing any effects form any zombies within the map making it possible for them to exist and letting the player be able to easily get zombie flesh.

Comment: Just wondering, why not `/kill` them instead of `/tp`ing them into the void?

Comment: @sharpturn `/kill` would leave any drops on the ground, potentially causing a great deal of lag if more and more spawn to be killed. Teleporting them into the void allows the void to kill them or, more likely, forces them to despawn. If killed, the drops are instantly deleted in the void. If despawned, then there's no worry of any drops at all.

Comment: Ah, okay. Thanks! Always wondered why, since I'm used to having `doMobLoot`off.

Comment: [16:40:46] You must specify which player you wish to perform this action on.......thats what i got s an output form the command block

Comment: @Palestina You have either typed in the command incorrectly or your clock mechanism is not properly set up. You also neglected to state *which* command block that error was for, but I am assuming it is for the `/tp` command. If you made any changes at all, you **must** state the new command(s) you're using. Otherwise nobody can know what's wrong.

Comment: I copy and paste the first 1.9 command and it says "The datatag does not match for" then codes with numbers and letters. Is there something else I'm forgetting?

Comment: @JordanRamirez The error in the command block is not going to be useful as it only represents the last iteration, while a proper zombie could have been located earlier. In this case you cannot rely on the command block itself because it will only succeed for a single tick as it won't re-target zombies it already labeled. Instead, you can quickly check for existing zombies with the label using `/testfor @e[type=Zombie,tag=ZombieVillager]`

Answer (score -1):

Zombie villagers are now considered a separate type of entity, making it possible to easily target only them:

```
/tp @e[type=zombie_villager] ~ -64 ~
```